# How to get second related value from List in ViewData MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewstate, viewbag

I have customer list which is having all details like
customerId,firstname,lastname

```
GetAllCustomer() method code
      var customer = from d in dbContext.Customers
                                           select d;
                return customer.ToList();
```

In Index.cs
I have bind firstname to dropdown list

```
var customerData =GetAllCustomer();

ViewBag.customerfirstname = new SelectList(customerData.Select(t=>t.firstname));
```

index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
        <p>
            customer name : @Html.DropDownList("customerfirstname", "All")
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> 

        </p>
}
```

> when I select any firstname from dropdown and click on submit
>    I also want its customerId too.

How can I do it so?

Comment: A `<select>` only posts back 1 value (or an array in the case of multiple) so you should be creating you `SelectList` with the value field based on the ID property and the text field based on the Name property (and bind to the ID property)

Comment: Firstly your form method should be Post, not Get. then in BeginForm you should put the name of the action in Home controller thats in charge of processing your form post. That action should have suitable model as input parameter, a model that will represent your form data.

Comment: @MladenOršolić, There is nothing in OP's code suggesting it needs to to be `FormMethod.Post`. The submit button has the text "Filter" suggesting it should in fact be a GET

Comment: This link provides examples on creating a drop-down in mvc http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify value field and text field for DropDownList, Now it will post CustomerID in for post against selected First Name :

```
var customerData =GetAllCustomer();

ViewBag.customerfirstname = new SelectList(customerData
                                           .Select(
                                                   t=>new 
                                                     { 
                                                      FirstName = t.firstname,
                                                     CustomerID = customerId),
                                          "CustomerID",
                                          "FirstName");
```

and then in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("customerfirstname", "All")
```

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("customerfirstname", "All"), will this code bind data from controller to drop down? Because you are passing a string instead of SelectList

Comment: yes it will string will be considered as viewbag key

Comment: @AmitKumar, The second parameter is for the `labelOption` - its adds `<option value="">All</option>` as the first option in the `<select>` element

Comment: @Anand writing ``@Html.DropDownList("customerfirstname")`` means that populate dropdown with ``IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`` which is in ``ViewBag.customerfirstname`` , if it not found ViewBag with the key then nothing happens otherwise it populates if found

Answer (score 1):

In your controller

```
ViewBag.customerfirstname  = new SelectList(customerData , "customerId", "firstname");
```

In your view , write this code to bind dropdown .

```
@Html.DropDownList("getcustomerfirstname", ViewBag.customerfirstname as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select")
```

Comment: when i will click on submit button how to get both values ?  on index action result method ?

Comment: What do you mean by both value?

Comment: you will get only Selected CustomerId. in your post action.